# Что есть "<<" и "|" в PHP

Tags: php

```
$alpha  = $color | ($transparency << 24);
$alpha2 = $color | (($maxTransparency - $transparency) << 24);
```

Столкнулся с таким кодом. Вы не могли бы расшифровать, что делают операторы "|" и "<<" в данном случае.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это называется битовые операции. О них можете почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/134557/).